# GNU emacs editor specifying window height and width (Windows8)

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am running GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows 8. I put the following 2 lines in my .emacs file to specify the height and width I want for the editor window:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'height 63))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width 125))
```

That works fine.  When I open another window from the main editor window using C-x 5 2, it starts up with the same width, but for some reason the height is 66, not 63.

Does anyone have thoughts on why this would happen?

Comment: I changed init.el to have height 63 for the initial-frame-alist, and height of 60 for default-frame-alist, which seems to properly adjust for the additional 3 rows in children frames.  Not elegant, but on my system, the initial and children frames are now the same height.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining the actual size of the resulting (new) frame? If you are using function `frame-parameters` then that's the right approach.

Are you starting from `emacs -Q`, so that you are sure that you are not loading some code from your init file that might interfere?

If so, and if you see a discrepancy between what `default-frame-alist` says a new frame should be like and what the new frame is actually like, then this is most likely a bug. You can report it, giving your recipe starting with `emacs -Q`, by doing `M-x report-emacs-bug`.